# Maven - Error when trying to build project

Tags: java, maven

I looked at the answer to someone who had a similar issue but I couldn't find it a solution to my problem. I'm unable to build my project:

```
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) @ myproject---
[INFO] configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.0.0
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.CiManagementReport
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project myproject: 
        Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: 
         A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent
```

I've added two plugins and a dependency which are the following, two plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

The dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
        <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated it, I generally don't understand what is left.

Comment: Upgrade the maven-site-plugin to most recent version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maven-site-plugin` in version 3.3 requires `doxia-site-renderer` 1.4, according to [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom). Is there a reason you included `doxia-site-renderer` dependency explicitly?

To solve the issue you can downgrade `doxia-site-renderer` to 1.4 or upgrade `maven-site-plugin` to 3.7 which requires `doxia-site-renderer` 1.8

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with no plugins configured. It seems that maven falls back to 3.3 of the site plugin when it is not there. I configured it for 3.7 and then the error disappeared. (Only getting css's and images at this point though.... :-() ) The site plugin gets the doxia thing implicitly so it should not be needed in the config.